# Return a default value when a match found

Tags: sql

I would like to return all records (entryIDs) and where the language flag is selected, I want to return Yes instead of the actual value in attributevalue field.  I've tried this but it returns the actual value populated rathern than a Yes where match found. I think I need where exists as this returns too many rows for each language associated with the entryIDs.

```
SELECT distinct x.entryID, ISNOTNULL(a.attributeValue, 'Yes')
from Entry as x
left outer join EntryAttribute as e on e.entryID = x.entryID
left outer join AttributeString as a on a.AttributeID = e.AttributeID 
where a.AttributeDefinitionID = 44
```

Comment: Did you roll your own `ISNOTNULL` function? If so the problem is probably there.

Comment: Where does the ISNOTNULL function come from?  Have you tried swapping parameters?   Which sql are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Use a CASE statement. For example:

```
CASE WHEN attributeValue IS NOT NULL THEN 'YES' ELSE 'NO' END
```